# Numerical series converges or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to ask how to prove if the series:

$\sqrt{n^2+1} - \sqrt{n^2 - 1}$

is convergent or divergent.

I tried [Cauchy criterion](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cauchy_criteria) but it doesn't work.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you mean series or sequence? Those are different things.

Comment: Yes it is series, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} \sqrt{n^2+1} - \sqrt{n^2-1} = \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+1} + \sqrt{n^2-1}}$$

But $\sqrt{n^2+1} + \sqrt{n^2-1} < 2n \Longleftrightarrow (n^2+1) + 2 \sqrt{n^2+1}\sqrt{n^2-1} + (n^2-1) < 4n^2 \Longleftrightarrow 4(n^4-1) < 4n^4$, which is true, so we have:

$$\sum\limits_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+1} + \sqrt{n^2-1}} > \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{2}{2n}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} H_n = + \infty, \, \blacksquare$$

so the series diverges.

Comment: A similar approach is to use the limit comparison theorem, with the relevant comparison being with the harmonic series.